# Getting sticky and collapse/expand work together with divs

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a number of divs that can be collapsed or expanded (Bootstrap v3.2.0) on clicking adjacent divs. Also, these divs are sticky through their content (Sticky-Kit - http://leafo.net/sticky-kit).

The page in question is here http://es.22web.org/sticky-collapse.html

The sticky works fine when all the divs are expanded. But, when I collapse one div, the heading of the collapsed div still sticks to it's previously expanded height.

The documentation on Sticky-Kit website says:

> If you're changing the markup of your page on the fly by removing,
>   adding or resizing elements then you most likely need to tell Sticky
>   Kit to recalculate the sticky elements to guarantee they're positioned
>   correctly.

So, I have added the code $(document.body).trigger("sticky_kit:recalc") to the onclick event (along with an alert to assure that the onclick event is triggered). But still the sticky doesn't work.

When a div is collapsed and again expanded, the sticky seems to have gotten reset and will not scroll down at all. It now gets fixed to the collapsed height of the div (actually this should have happened when collapsed).

Am not able to get both the sticky and collapse/expand work together.

I want the Section links to stick down only when their content divs are expanded. Unable to get this done.

Please help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after playing with the scroll and sticky page, I figure out that the sticky element recalculate function was called well before the divs collapsed or expanded.

So, thought to delay the onclick event by 1sec by which time the div would have finished ecpanded or collapsed. This worked like a magic.

Here is what I added to the onclick event:

```
$(".myclass").click(function(){
setTimeout(function (){
$(document.body).trigger("sticky_kit:recalc");
}, 1000);
});
});
```

Hope this helps someone facing similar kind of problem.

Thanks.